# Window doesn't appear using Tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

This is the file I launch with python :

```
from Tkinter import *

# Esempio di GUI

def main():
    w1 = Tk()
    w1.title("Finestra 1")
    f1 = Frame(w1)
    f1.pack()
    w1.mainloop()

main()
```

The program is in execution, but I don't see any window appearing.
I have to close the terminal window to stop, I don't get why.

Comment: On my system, the window appears, but is only a few pixels wide at the upper-left corner.

Comment: it's never a good practice to do `import *`, and even worst if you don't even know what's in the module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Give the frame a width and height:

```
from Tkinter import *

# Esempio di GUI

def main():
    w1=Tk()
    w1.title("Finestra 1")
    # Width, height in pixels
    f1=Frame(w1, height=50, width=50)
    f1.pack()
    w1.mainloop()

main()
```

Answer (score 2):

Because there is no real content in the window, only an empty frame, the window will be as small as possible. On some systems it may be completely invisible. Try modifying main() and see what happens

```
def main():
    w1=Tk()
    w1.title("Finestra 1")
    f1=Frame(w1)
    b = Button(f1, text='asldkf')
    b.pack()
    f1.pack()
    w1.mainloop()
```